# Laravel - Compatible session for different subdomains

Tags: php, laravel, session, subdomain

I have one Larav app working on subd1.example.com, working properly and with this config as part or config/session.php

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')
'cookie' => 'subd1examplecom'
'path' => '/'
'domain' => env("DOMAIN", "subd1.example.com")
```

The thing is we have a different domain subd2.example.com with:

- Different front layout
- Same laravel app as dubd1
- Same database as dubd1
- Same storage folder as dubd1

But the subd2.example.com is not working as the session is conflicting the other one.

CAn you help on how to manage please?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using sub-domain routing through Laravel or a different installation?

Comment: Hi @ponury-kostek. Not sure of what you mean. Subdomain rewrite rules are managed at apache config both pointing to the same /public/index.php. Then, at LocaleMiddleware.php and based on the subdomain requested i am setting a flag in the session to change layouts

Comment: You want a joint session for both subdomains? Did you set a `DOMAIN` value in `.env`?

Comment: Nope. User would reach both subdomains for same purpose but for different brands. My .env DOMAIN is subd1.example.com

Comment: Anyone please ?